# Volume control with DS1807 digital potentiometer?

Tags: audio, analog, potentiometer

I'm making a digital synth for a project and I need to wire in an Arduino-controlled volume circuit.

Right now I'm outputting a 0-5V audio signal and cutting it down to a pure AC 0.5V signal with a voltage divider (1kohms and 10ohms) and a capacitor. I would like to tack on a digital potentiometer to this circuit to control the audio volume so I bought a DS1807.

The datasheet is [here](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/DS1807%2B/DS1807%2B-ND/1197186) but I'm still not totally sure how to use this -- it refers to the resistor settings in db rather than ohms, but it feels like I should be putting in a second resistor to form a voltage divider with it. What should that resistor value be? I don't see a reference to what the actual resistance of the DS1807 varies between. Or am I thinking about this circuit completely wrong?

(p.s., the speaker we'll use is a powered computer speaker)

Here's the circuit I was thinking of-- is that correct and how do I choose R3?

Thanks!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7fguR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The potentiometer global resistance is said to be about 45KΩ so there's no need for the additional dividing resistance (100KΩ), as @meakcey writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need additional resistor. Just wire audio signals to digital pot pins H0-L0 or H1-L1. W0 or W1 will give you divided signal.
Pot values are indicated in datasheet page 10.

Also be carefull not to avoid recomended limits again indicated on page 10.

Comment: oh, duh, because there's now a resistor on the left *and* right side of the wiper! so I put the audio signal on H0 and ground on L0 then?

Comment: yes. you could think it as normal potentiometer.
also i you could find code related link
http://hackaday.com/2009/02/16/parts-i2c-audio-volume-potentiometer-ds1807/

Comment: i didn't see "then?" =)
between W0 and L0 pin, you would get what you gave with i2c interface